# Multiple projects in one solution like nopCommerce 3.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

How do I create 2 ASP.NET MVC projects in a single solution, similar to nopCommerce 3.5? The two projects would be:

1. Web project at http://localhost:15536
2. Admin project at http://localhost:15536/Admin

Comment: FYI in Nop commerce there is no multiple project run, Admin is an area in nop commerce   please look this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 0):

In NopCommerce physically there's no two project,

If you go physically you'll find the Nop.Admin project is under the Nop.Web project , and you have to create the second project and you refer to the http://localhost:15536 project in Visual studio and add the second project with add an existing project and you have to implement AreaRegistration to specify your Url in this second project and of corse your dll have to be generated under /bin of the first project.

Best Regards